# Why does `head` not want to give me the filename on top of the `find` list?

Tags: command-line, find, execute-command

I need to pick the least recently played sound file from one directory and put it in another. I tried:

```
find /home/carl/music/rock/SE/ -name "*_" -printf '%A@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n 1 -exec cp {} /home/carl/playout_rock_SE/ \;
```

I get:

```
head: invalid option - - ’e’
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative that avoids `head`ing and `sed`ing (and should also be safe for any legal filenames):

```
find /home/carl/music/rock/SE/ -name "*_" -printf '%A@\t%p\0' |
  sort -znk1,1 | { read -r -d '' t f; cp -v -- "$f" "/home/carl/playout_rock_SE/" ; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a pipe, the command before the pipe is finished. You cannot resume your `find` command with `-exec` on the other side of it. The `head` command thinks `-exec` is a series of options for it, but it has no such option as `-e`, hence "invalid option"

If your filenames don't have spaces or other weird characters, you should be able to manage like this:

```
find /home/carl/music/rock/SE/ -name "*_" -printf '%A@ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n 1 | sed 's/.* //' | xargs -p -I '{}' cp -v -- '{}' /home/carl/playout_rock_SE/
```

- `sed 's/.* //'` removes the timestamp now that we've picked out the file (this strips everything up to and including the first space)
- `-p` interactive - confirm before executing the command
- `-I` replace string - so that we can place the input filename before the destination to give `cp` correct syntax
- `cp -v --` tell us what is being copied and treat anything after this as an argument, even if it looks like an option

However, I recommend using [steeldriver's much more reliable answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/866364/527764) instead ;)

Comment: Hey thanks! The error went away bt the file wasn´t copied

Comment: @carlos works for me as far as I can test on my own system - what output are you getting?